# Extracting index value from list, by passing a variable through a function

Tags: python

I am trying to get the index value of list, based on the variable that is passed into the function. I have hard coded it to illustrate the correct results. Hence, 'neighbors' should return the previous zip code, the entered zip code, and the next zip code (3 zip codes in total).

```
def foo(zip):
    zipcodes = [11105,11102,11103,11104,11377,11373,11372,11368]
    neighbors = []
    if zip in zipcodes:
  #     x = "index of zip"
  #     num = zipcodes[x]  --> i.e. x = 4
        num1 = 4-1 # x - 1
        num2 = 4+2 # x + 2
        neighbors = zipcodes[num1:num2] 
        print neighbors

foo(11377)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function :

```
>>> def foo(zip,zipcodes):
...     x=zipcodes.index(zip)
...     if x==0 :
...       return zipcodes [:2]
...     elif x==len(zipcodes):
...       return zipcodes [-2:]
...     return zipcodes[x-1:x+2]
... 
>>> zipcodes = [11105,11102,11103,11104,11377,11373,11372,11368]
>>> foo(11105,zipcodes)
[11105, 11102]
>>> foo(11368,zipcodes)
[11372, 11368]
>>> foo(11104,zipcodes)
[11103, 11104, 11377]
```

Comment: It's a small error but this will not produce a result for 11105.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close to the solution, just find the appropriate index with `list.index(element)`

```
def foo(zip):
    zipcodes = [11105,11102,11103,11104,11377,11373,11372,11368]
    neighbors = []
    if zip in zipcodes:
        x = zipcodes.index(zip)
        num1 = x-1 
        num2 = x+2 
        # ensure that idx doesn't get -1
        if num1<0: num1=0 
        neighbors = zipcodes[num1:num2] 
        print neighbors
foo(11377)
```

Edit: Also make sure, your num1-idx doesn't get -1 as that will not produce the correct result.